# Remote PSSession telnet not working

Tags: powershell, telnet

When I start a remote PS session and I execute the command `telnet 1.2.3.4` nothing happens a new line just starts.
If I RDP to server and start PS, execute the same command the telnet session opens just fine. How can I make this work in a remote PS Session?

See screenshot for more info.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by "new line just starts"? How did you establish the PS session? What did you do to make the `telnet` command to be run on the session rather than local?

Comment: Due to firewall rules i can't telnet to the device from my machine. Also added a screenshot

Comment: The computer name is placed in front of the telnet line after you use `Enter-PSSession`, you forgot to redact it in that space. So it does work if you use the same machine? You could try to check `$?` for an error code that would indicate that `telnet` wasn't run successfully.

Comment: TY Redacted it now :). When I first run the `telnet` and then `$?` it says `true`. I have no idea what that means. Better should've posted I'm new to PS.

Comment: It would tell you whenever the last command ran successfully. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180074/what-does-command-do-mean-in-powershell) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Automatic_Variables). So you do get a connection if you directly RDP into the server using the same user?

Comment: This is the same user but in RDP session [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/2MkRrdy.png). What I think is wrong after reading up, is that telnet is not using the PS stdin/stdout. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Indeed it appears that telnet is "broken" [in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871848/how-to-get-telnet-output-on-powershell). You could look into a solution like [this](https://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/04/04/using-powershell-as-a-telnet-client/) if you want to use PS for it. Otherwise consider using an alternative client like [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) which supports [parameters](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's because telnet is an interactive program. Powershell doesn't handle interactive programs like telnet, because I had the same issue using git when it's supposed to prompt you for credentials. [This person here had the same issue as us basically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466372/execution-of-interactive-command-in-remote-powershell-session-not-working). I haven't tried it myself, but maybe telnet cmdlets in [this powershell module is worth a shot.](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NetCmdlets/16.0.6255.0)